# Ionic2 Popover Change Width

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to change the popover width of only 1 page.
I tried this:

I do not want to use this `$popover-ios-width` in variable.scss files
since it changes the width on all pages.

Answer (score 14):

You can create a custom class for only this popover and pass it in the `cssClass` on it's options

let's say you have this:

```
.custom-popover {
  width: 60%;
}
```

In your popover creation you'll just insert it as the cssClass on the options

```
const customPopOver = this.popover.create({ yourPopoverPage, yourData, { cssClass: 'custom-popover'}});
customPopOver.present();
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: I put the .customer-popover class in my .scss file and called from my .ts file the popover with the same name, it is still the same size

Comment: the `.custom-popover` class should be declared globally as **ion-popover** is not on the same context as the page component.

Comment: as @afifahmi said it needs to be globally, put your .customer-popover in the `app.scss` file inside app folder.

Comment: @GabrielBarreto where would I put this if I am using an ion-select with the popover interface?

Answer (score 14):

@gabriel-barreto's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44006006/2732057) is totally fine. However, I guess it needs an additional consideration in other versions.

In Ionic 3.6 the custom class is added to the `<ion-popover>` element. In order to override the default width rule set in `.popover-content` class, your selector should be:

```
.custom-popover .popover-content {
  width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Still valid with ionic 4.4.0

Answer (score 3):

Add this below code in `variables.scss`. works for me in `Ionic 4`.

```
ion-popover {
  .popover-wrapper {
   .popover-content {
     width: fit-content;
     max-width: 300px;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: This still works for Ionic 5, however I don't think this is the recommended way. In the docs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#css-custom-properties) they describe custom css properties: --max-width and --width. Issue is: I just don't have a clue how to use them and it's not described anywhere. Any idea?

Comment: The solution also works for `Ionic 5`. I will do the recommended way later. Until then you can use this solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @MD. IBRAHIM KHALIL TANIM

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it will still suit you, I found the same problem, but modifying the global variable scss configuration did not help me because I used multiple PopoverControllers in the project the only way I managed to do it is the following:

1. Place the ion-content as a parent element and add the id attribute
2. Get Parent Items to the Main Container:

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
    let element = document.getElementById('id')
    let parent=element.parentElement
    let parent2 = parent.parentElement //popover-content
    parent2.parentElement.style['width'] = "92px"
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks Ill try that

Comment: Can you post your html? I am confused which ion-content

Comment: <ion-content id="align-format">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
    Align
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item (tap)="setAlign('left')"><i class="fa fa-align-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></ion-item>
    <ion-item (tap)="setAlign('center')"><i class="fa fa-align-center fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></ion-item>
    <ion-item (tap)="setAlign('right')"><i class="fa fa-align-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></ion-item>
    <ion-item (tap)="setAlign('justify')"><i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
myPopOver = this.popovercontroller.create({ component: MyCustomComponent, 
               event:ev, 
               cssClass: 'my-custom-popover'
})
    
myPopOver.present();
```

**add my-custom-popover class in global.css file.**

Answer (score 1):

```
const customPopOver = this.popover.create({ yourPopoverPage, yourData, { cssClass: 'custom-popover'}});
```

You need to create popover and add cssClass prop as on code above, then you can use 'custom-popover' class in variables.scss file like below.

```
.custom-popover {
.popover-wrapper {
  .popover-content {
    width: 465px;
  }
}
```

}